# EcmaScript5 features

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

I have a fair knowledge of ES3, but I'm not really up to date about the features of ES5. I - more or less - know about:

- `Object.create()`, `Object.freeze()`
- `"use strict"`
- getters and setters
- the methods `map()`, `filter()`, `every()`, `some()` of Array.prototype
- `JSON.parse()`

but I'm sure I am missing other goodies. Moreover, I do not know all the details about the above: for instance I am not sure about all the effects of `"use strict"`.

> Is there a good resource where to learn all the ins and outs of ES5, in particular constrsting it to ES3, short of reading the [final final final final draft](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-262.pdf)?

Comment: Are they not? They seem to work in Node, which is based on V8.

Comment: my bad, I got confused. There still bad because there's no way to support ES5 with that kind of syntax (You can't monkey patch or simulate it)

Comment: You have read the official documentation? http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-262.pdf

Comment: I have linked it in my question, explicitly asking if there is a source **other** than that. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the [Compliance table](http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table/)

Then just search for each feature on the MDN.

There's also an article by [john resig](http://ejohn.org/blog/ecmascript-5-objects-and-properties/)

There also seems to be a [page at Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/JavaScript/ECMAScript_5_support_in_Mozilla)